# Efficient way to do unions and intersections in mySQL

Tags: mysql, logic, boolean, union, intersection

I have a mySQL table with columns: name and label. If a person, "Bob" has the labels "cool","funny", and "childish", my table would have the corresponding rows: (Bob, cool), (Bob, funny), and (Bob, childish).

Is there an efficient way to select people based on labels with a boolean query? For example, in pseudo-SQL: SELECT name WHERE person IS (COOL OR NOT FUNNY) AND NOT CHILDISH.

I think I could hack something together using UNION, JOIN, maybe some sub-queries, but I was wondering if there was an efficient way to do this.

EDIT:

As of now, I am planning to distribute AND, ie ((COOL OR NOT FUNNY) AND NOT CHILDISH) => (COOL AND NOT CHILDISH) OR (NOT FUNNY AND NOT CHILDISH). And then I can determine each of the parts that are OR'd together with something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.name
FROM `tags` AS a
JOIN `tags` AS b ON (a.label='cool' AND a.name=b.name AND b.name NOT IN (
    SELECT name FROM `tags` WHERE label='funny'))
JOIN `tags` AS c ON (a.name=c.name AND c.name='childish')
# for "COOL AND NOT FUNNY AND CHILDISH"
```

And then use UNION to join them together.

Comment: I think thats about as efficient as it gets. I wouldn't know of any other way to make it more efficient and can't think of any.

Answer (score 2):

For the negative checks, the most efficient way would be to use `MINUS` as follows:

```
SELECT NAME
FROM NAME_LABEL
WHERE LABEL IN ('COOL') -- use IN for easy matching of multiple labels
UNION
SELECT NAME
FROM NAME_LABEL NL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM NAME_LABEL WHERE NAME = NL.NAME AND LABEL IN ('FUNNY')) 
MINUS
SELECT NAME
FROM NAME_LABEL
WHERE LABEL IN ('CHILDISH');
```

The `MINUS` keyword selects distinct rows from the first query and *don't* appear in the second query.

Performance would be better with an index on `LABEL`:

```
CREATE INDEX NAME_LABEL_NAME ON NAME_LABEL(NAME);
```

Unfortunately, the "NOT FUNNY" requires an EXISTS subquery. If you use a join, the MySQL query optimizer turns it into a subselect anyway :(

Comment: To create any "logical expression" then, would MINUS, INTERSECTION, and UNION suffice?

Comment: How does the WHERE NOT EXISTS compare to SELECT * MINUS FUNNY in terms of efficiency? Sorry, I'm just learning SQL.

Comment: It's as good as it gets. Unfortunately the `EXISTS()` part is not very efficient. `INTERSECTION` means `AND` logic between rowsets, which you didn't need. `UNION` simply adds the two rowsets together, sorting them and discarding duplicates (note that `UNION ALL` doesn't discard duplicates and preserves row order). `MINUS` removes matching rows from the preceding rowset.

Comment: mySQL does not support MINUS/INTERSECT. Does that leave me with subqueries?